# Generate all vectors of certain length with 0 or 1 elements

Tags: r, vector, combinations

I need to generate all possible vectors with elements 0 or 1 of a certain length.

For example, here the length is 6, I need all the vectors:

```
(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,1),...,(1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Searching around, I found a way to make the vector `y` below which contains 64 character strings `"000000","000001",...,"111111"`, but now I am stuck not knowing how to convert each of these strings into the relevant vector.

```
x <- seq(0,2^6-1,1)
library(R.utils)
y <- inToBin(x)
```

**Edit:** I figured out how to do this:

```
z <- matrix(NA,nrow=length(y),ncol=6)
for(i in 1:length(y)){
  z[i,] <- as.numeric(strsplit(y[i],"")[[1]])
}
```

Comment: The phrase to use is *"all combinations of {0,1} of length 6"*. That'll help you find the right function faster...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `expand grid` and `combn` functions are your first thought when trying to construct exhaustive examples of combinations. Here I think you want the `expand.grid` facility.:

```
 str( apply(expand.grid(0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1), 1, paste0, collapse="") )

 chr [1:64] "000000" "100000" "010000" "110000" "001000" ...
```

But perhaps you don't really want that and only want

```
apply(expand.grid(0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1), 1, list)
```

Or just:

```
expand.grid(0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1)
```

Comment: If you want it as a character vector, consider `apply(expand.grid(0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1,0:1), 1, as.character)` which gives it to you as a character 64 x 6 matrix.

Comment: The third way is exactly what I need, in one line!!! I wish I could give you 5 votes up!